# unity3d web player data file corrupt

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity-web-player

I have a unity3d game that I am trying to deploy with unity web player. I have uploaded it to my cdn. On my machine it opens up fine in Firefox and safari. But on some machines it gives the `Data file is corrupt (not a Unity Web Player file)` error.

Solutions on google included setting the Content-Type to `application/vnd.unity` or `application/x-unity`. but this didn't work for me. Other than that i couldn't find any useful knowledge.

If it fails to open on a specific machine it fails in Firefox and safari.

The game is here: https://fabula-cdn.global.ssl.fastly.net/games/oneononefootball/1.1.0/WebPlayer/WebPlayer.html?1234&dev&on&1.1.0

any ideas?
thanks

Comment: The Unity web player is no longer supported by chrome. Try exporting you game as webGL

Comment: not using it on chrome... the error happens on firefox and safari

Comment: You're right, I see it on safari as well. I have no idea honestly, my only suggestion would be to tra exporting in webgl